# Как принять человека в закрытый телеграм-канал с помощью бота, который пишет пользователю первым?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, asyncio, aiogram-3.x

Задача стоит в том, что пользователь отправляет заявку, бот ему пишет с предложением подтвердить запрос с помощью нажатия на инлайн кнопку (в дальнейшем планирую добавить между этими действиями дополнительные функции), после нажатия на кнопку запрос одобряется.
Использую aiogram.
Я видел ветки, где объясняется, как написать автоприем в одной функции, и моя трудность заключается в том, чтобы разбить это на две функции (реакция бота на заявку и принятие пользователя в тгк после нажатия пользователем на кнопку).

Буду безумно благодарен если поможете, тк навыков не хватает, чтобы разобраться самому.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хендлером на заявку в закрытый канал является функция `chat_join_request`

Перед тестированием бота нужно предоставить ему привилегии на принятие участников в закрытом канале.

```py
from aiogram import Dispatcher, F
from aiogram.types import ChatJoinRequest

dp.chat_join_request.filter(F.chat.id == -123456789) # Принимаем заявки определённого канала

@dp.chat_join_request() # Хендлер на заявку в закрытый канал
async def test(update: ChatJoinRequest):
    await update.approve() # Бот одобряет заявку
    await update.bot.send_message(update.from_user.id,"Мы приняли Вашу заявку!") # и отправляет сообщение пользователю
```

Примечание: по правилам Telegram, бот не может писать первым пользователю. Исключением является принятие в закрытый канал.

Comment: вот да, он ловит заявку и принимает ее в одной функции, а мне нужно разделить ее, чтобы хендлер ловил заявку и сохранял ее где то, как я понимаю, а во второй независимой функции уже аппрувал ее, так понимаю, что нужно подключать какую-нибудь  бдшку, но честно говоря, не особо понимаю как это реализовать

Comment: Не понимаю зачем для этого разделять функции. Вы можете сначала обработать БД, потом уже аппрувить. Но если всё же Вам надо передать переменную в другую функцию, то можно записать её в машину состояния через MemoryStorage